# how to control the img attributes src in fetching the data from database in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, axios

I am creating a article related project. And A article can we wrriten by multiple author.In this I want to show image on webpage if it has src and if it has no src then show empty.I fatched the data by using axios

```
<img className="userpic" src={item.author[0].picture} alt="" />
<img className="userpic" src={item.author[1].picture} alt="" />
<img className="userpic" src={item.author[2].picture} alt="" />
```

currently the above code is working because in author table all id has the picture.But suppose If there is no picture inside the author[2] then I am getting the error on console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined
```

How can we solve it?

Comment: Based on that error you'd need to do `{% if item.author[0] %}item.author[0].picture{% endif %}`

Comment: @markwalker_ how can we implement this in reactjs by using axios.

Comment: Just the usual way to make sure something is defined `if(item.author[0] !== undefined){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img className="userpic" src={item.author[0] ? item.author[0].picture : 'default_image_url'} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use default image

```
const image = item.author[0].picture 
<img src={image === 'undifiend'
 ?  // put the path of default image
: 
image} class="img-fluid" />
```

Comment: getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined`